# SonarQube issue expected an assignment or function call instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to count the number of selected items from array of object.
I am facing

> expected assignment or function call issue in sonarQube

Need some help to solve the issue.

```
const dataList = [
   { label: "test1", value: "test1", checked: true },
   { label: "test2", value: "test2", checked: false },
   { label: "test3", value: "test3", checked: true }];
     
const getSelectedCount2 = (dataList) => {
   let selectedItemCount = 0;
   dataList.forEach(item => item.checked ? selectedItemCount = selectedItemCount + 1 : "" );

   return selectedItemCount;
}
```

problematic line is

```
dataList.forEach(item => item.checked ? selectedItemCount = selectedItemCount + 1 : "" );`
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning an empty line in `false` part for ternary is what causes the error. You can simply increment `selectedItemCount` with `if` expression within the loop:

```
const getSelectedCount2 = (dataList) => {
    let selectedItemCount = 0;

    dataList.forEach(item => { 
        if (item.checked) { selectedItemCount++; }
    });

    return selectedItemCount;
}
```

or use it simply as:

```
const getSelectedCount2 = dataList => {
    return dataList.filter(item => item.checked).length;
}
```